# What should happen to off-topic Tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's maybe a little bit early to ask that question, but it can occur, that questions are asked, which are off-topic, and a tag is created therefore. Example: [How could Aang stay alive for 100 years?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/498/how-does-ang-stay-alive-for-100-years) [avatar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar).

As discussed in the question, avatar is not topic of AaM, hence the question is closed. But what should happen to these tags? If I see the tag, I think "Hey, there's a tag for it, so I can ask!". Should be anything done about wrong/off-topic tags?

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, an off-topic question should later be deleted. Once it is deleted, the tag becomes orphaned and will soon after be removed by the system.

Comment: Just wondering, how long does it usually take for the unused tags to be deleted?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I believe the script runs nightly, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: ok, thanks ;) I was just curious

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a problem, though I can see your point.

I doubt that the presence of a tag will force people to use it. Think about it, what does one do when he wants to ask a question? First of all, he tries to search for if the question already exists. Lets assume it doesn't. Now, one will press "ask question" button. After that he creates a title, writes the question itself, and *only then* he goes to the tags. DO you really think that after doing all that the absence of the tag in auto-completion list is going to stop him? Unlikely.

I personally agree with the point expressed in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2524) on meta.math. It states that there is a *tagging problem* only if the tags are *inaccurate*, while if the tags are *accurate*, there is no problem, no matter if the tags (and the question itself) are on-topic or not.